# Large data transfer using wsDualHttpbinding fails

Tags: wcf, out-of-memory, wcf-callbacks, wsdualhttpbinding, duplex-channel

I'm trying to send data of size greater than 25 MB to multiple clients at the same time using callbacks. I have implemented the service with wsdualhttp binding. It throws "System.OutofMemory" and "Failed to allocate memory" exceptions when the service tries to send  the data to more than 3 clients concurrently. I have set relevant values for serviceThrottling,  maxItemsInObjectGraph as well as  maxBufferPoolSize. Also, I cannot use streaming. Is there a way to achieve this?

// Server Side

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.net>
<connectionManagement>
  <add address="*" maxconnection="2147483647"/>
</connectionManagement>
</system.net>  
<system.serviceModel>     
  <bindings>
   <wsDualHttpBinding>
     <binding name="WSConfig" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" 
              receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
              transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
              maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" >
       <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
       <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"/>
     </binding>
   </wsDualHttpBinding>
 </bindings>     
 <services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior"     name="CallbackService.MycallbackService">
     <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/MycallbackService/MyService" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="CallbackService.IServiceContract" bindingConfiguration="WSConfig">
         <identity>
         <dns value="localhost"/>
       </identity>           
     </endpoint>                 
   </service>       
 </services>
 <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
     <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
       <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
       <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false "/>
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="2147483647" maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" maxConcurrentSessions="1000"/>
       <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>           
     </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
 </behaviors>      
</system.serviceModel>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>    
</configuration>
```

//Client Side

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.net>
<connectionManagement>
  <add address ="*" maxconnection = "2147483647" />
</connectionManagement>
</system.net>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsDualHttpBinding>
    <binding name ="WSConfig" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
   openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00"
   bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
   maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
   messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
      maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"/>
    </binding>
  </wsDualHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/MycallbackService/MyService" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="CallbackService.IServiceContract" bindingConfiguration ="WSConfig">     
  </endpoint>
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
</startup>
```

Comment: does it fail serverside or client-side? Can you share the binding config?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: please post your config file. Is it an OK solution to set the limit the number of concurrent callbacks?

Comment: @rene: I have shared the config file.

Comment: @Jocke: I don't think the problem is with number of concurrent calls.

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking into this: I've had the same problem and it turned out that  the data exchanged were too big for the serlializer/deserializer. This in turn caused System.OutofMemory errors. You may want to try some other binding (For example NetTcpBinding which supports binary encoding)

Also: Make sure that both your client and service are compiled for the same architecture (if your service addresses a 64bit namespace and your client compiled for 32bit, then you're bound to get System.OutofMemory exceptions